# How To Make files in `/usr/local` Writable For Homebrew?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, homebrew

I've been trying to get homebrew working nicely, but it appears everything inside `/usr/local` isn't writable, and everything falls over.

It keeps telling me to recursively `chown` `/usr/local`, and I tried that. Operation denied, so I sudo'd it. It seemed to work, but with an eerie silence that I hear is considered polite in Unix. Unfortunately, any succeeding attempts at `brew update` meet with the same cacophony of errors.

I reran the command with `-v` and it looks the operation is not permitted for anything inside.

As much as the answer is probably "learn UNIX" I'm just trying to comply with some job requirements here for a tutorial on Ruby, so that's a few steps above where I'm currently at.

`brew doctor`:

```
Warning: /usr/local/Frameworks isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/Frameworks
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar isn't writable.
You should `chown` /usr/local/Cellar
Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc
Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/include
Warning: /usr/local/lib isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib
Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
Warning: /usr/local/opt isn't writable.
You should `chown` /usr/local/opt
Warning: /usr/local/share isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/share
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man
    /usr/local/share/man/man1
    /usr/local/share/man/man3
    /usr/local/share/man/man5
    /usr/local/share/man/man7
    /usr/local/share/man/man8
Warning: /usr/local/var isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/var
```

Comment: Does `brew doctor` tell you anything useful? Post the output here.

Comment: @IanC. It's a long list of everything brew-related not being writable. Is there a stackexchange pastebin utility? There's an *awful lot* of it.

Comment: Well, that's odd. There's a lot less of it now than there was.

Comment: Just FYI: I just ran `brew update` and discovered that "Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local." More info in this [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/how-does-homebrew-no-longer-need-ownership-of-usr-local). Obviously to get to that point you'd still need to temporarily update permissions on /usr/local :)

Comment: Can someone explain to me why mac got rid of our permissions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should be solved changing the perms on that directory in the following way:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ sudo chown -R <your-username>:<your-group-name> *
```

If you don't know your group, just type `id -g`.

Comment: The important part is the `-R` to make it recursive. And you probably have to do the `chown` using `sudo`. For the user group, I usually use `staff` on OS X.

Comment: Interesting. Why is using the group so different from just the user?

Comment: This solved the first problem, but now I have another one. I ask a different question for that, right? This time brew's complaining about a git .lock

Comment: The group is just to be sure that works, may or may not be necessary. Regarding you new issue, ask a new question.

Comment: Why is it right for /usr/local to be owned by your user? I think that is a security risk, as there are a lot of other programs that use /usr/local and could be silently taken over. Does brew really need something so drastic?

Comment: I believe this is dangerous as it selects the 'staff' group, which means every user on the OS can then alter the contents of /usr/.  You should probably switch to 'admin'.

Comment: @dfrankow yep, this is a blunder of homebrew. They didn't think even what happens if there're two users on same machine.

Comment: Pretty sure this creates a security vulnerability. However it is the official suggested solution from brew.

Comment: It keeps telling me "r11g is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: @dfrankow (and others) Yes it's a security vulnerability and it's pathetic of homebrew. It's reason enough to not use it. I use MacPorts instead. Unfortunate as I do want to test something with homebrew but there's not a chance of that whilst it requires taking over /usr/local.

Comment: In fact Sophos writes to */usr/local* so it's just madness to let the user own the directory. I'm sure applications do too.

Answer (score 28):

You have to use [sudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) to run the command with elevated priledges, like this:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/*
```

Comment: I did. "Operation denied, so I sudo'd it."

Comment: For fish shell users it will be `sudo chown -R (whoami) /usr/local`

Comment: This must be done of the files/folders inside of /usr/local but not on this directory per se, e.g. ```sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/*```

Comment: haha.. very elegant.

Comment: @HenriqueGontijo good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 17):

I was facing this issue yesterday with macOS 10.13.4 and I tried to `sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local` or `sudo chown -R <your-username>:<your-group-name> /usr/local` which get `Operation not permitted` error even though using `sudo`

So I tried to just `chgrp` for `Homebrew` related folder to `admin` (My user is in `admin` group, depends on the user you are running, you might need to change to a different group) and grant `admin` group write access to those folders using these commands

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local/Homebrew/
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/Homebrew/
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local/var/homebrew/
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/var/homebrew/
```

After running these commands, I am able to install a new package without any issue. If you hit any permission issue again try to run the first two commands by replacing the folder name with the one that you are hitting permission issue.

Hope this will help the other users with macOS 10.13.

> Note: Even though changing the owner for `/usr/local` or changing the group of `/usr/local` and grant the access for you group might work, you should NEVER do that as you are modifying the other unrelated folder as well. Modifying the folder(s) you need is much more secure.

Answer (score 14):

The answer by Reza in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459152/cant-chown-usr-local-for-homebrew-in-mac-os-x-10-13-high-sierra) worked for me:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*`

> You can not change permission for /usr/local itself , but you can change the right permission for folders underneath

Answer (score 2):

to resolve the permissions issues on the directories we can perform the following command:

```
brew prune
```

Comment: `brew prune` has been replaced by and is now run as part of `brew cleanup`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local
```