# How to Change File Permissions for directories used by Homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, permission

I got this error when I tried to install Mingw-w64 C++ Compiler through Homebrew, and I can't figure out how to solve it since I tried several methods, but they weren't effective. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Error: The following directories are not writeable by your user:
/usr/local/share/zsh

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/zsh
(base) macbook-Air:~ Rawan$
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have to change the permissions like this.  Are you using `sudo` when attempting the install?

Comment: What are the paragraphs after the line starting with Error? Are these also part of the error message or things you have tried or simply came across while searching on this issue?

Comment: I don't have any experience with that, so I don't know anything about (sudo). I searched about it, but I don't understand that.

Comment: I copied what showed on terminal screen so I don't know what are the paragraphs after the line started ..

Comment: See this question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/192227/119271 and see [this tutorial](https://www.unixtutorial.org/how-to-use-sudo/) on `sudo`

Comment: Please provide the command line you are trying to use to install MinGW.  What version of Homebrew?  What is the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: The output recommends two commands you should run. Did you do so, and what was the result?